# Is it Possible to navigate from createStackNavigator to createDrawerNavigator?

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer

How is this implemented

I have a stack navigator which i use for Splashscreen and Login, this works fine , now i have a drawerNavigator which is the main home of the Application, Now my worry is, Is this possible , navigating from a stack navigator (username and password) and landing at a homepage (DrawerNavigator) (home page with left side menu)

My code is looking something like this, its a very long code I know, but pls at the same time, I just started out react-native some few days ago. Does anyone think its advisable to use createStackNavigator as well as createDrawerNavigator at the same time?

```
import React , {Component} from 'react';
import {  Platform, View, Text, Image , StyleSheet , ActivityIndicator, Dimensions, Modal, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, Alert } from 'react-native';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation-drawer';
import { Header } from 'react-native-elements';
import { Left, Right, Icon } from 'native-base';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';

class SplashScreen extends React.Component{
  componentDidMount()
  {
      setTimeout(() => {
          this.props.navigation.navigate('Login')
      }, 4000);
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <View style={styles.Logocontainer}>
      <Image
          source={{uri: 'LOGO IMAGE HERE'}}
       style={styles.logo} />

       <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="blue" style={{margin:10}}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class Login extends React.Component{

  login(){
    const {username, password} = this.state;
    Alert.alert('Login Successful');
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <View style={styles.Logocontainer}>
      <Image
  source={{uri: 'LOGO IMAGE HERE'}}
style={styles.logo} />

    <Text style={{textAlign:'left',fontSize:25,color: '#009999'}}> Sign In {"\n"}</Text>
<TextInput
 onChangeText={(username) => this.setState({ username })}
placeholder = "Username"
style={styles.input}
/>

<TextInput
 onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({ password })}
placeholder = "Password"
style={styles.input}
secureTextEntry={true} />

<TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={this.login.bind(this)}>
<Text style={styles.loginbtn}> Login </Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
</View>
    );
  }
}

class Home extends React.Component{
  static navigationOptions = {
    drawerLabel: 'Home',
    drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
      <Image
        source={{uri:'http://imageholder.freeasphost.net/home.png'}}
        style={[styles.icon, { tintColor: tintColor }]}
      />
    ),
  };

  render()
  {
    return(
      <View style={styles.container}>
       <Header
          leftComponent={<Icon name="menu" onPress={() => this.props.navigation.openDrawer()} />}
        />
        <View style={styles.text}>
        <Text> Welcome to Home screen</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class Profile extends React.Component{
  static navigationOptions = {
    drawerLabel: 'Profile',
    drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
      <Image
        source={{uri:'http://imageholder.freeasphost.net/profile.png'}}
        style={[styles.icon, { tintColor: tintColor }]}
      />
    ),
  };
  render()
  {
    return(
      <View style={styles.container}>
         <Header
          leftComponent={<Icon name="menu" onPress={() => this.props.navigation.openDrawer()} />}
        />
        <View style={styles.text}>
        <Text>Welcome to Profile screen</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class Settings extends React.Component{
  static navigationOptions = {
    drawerLabel: 'Settings',
    drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
      <Image
        source={{uri:'http://imageholder.freeasphost.net/settings.png'}}
        style={[styles.icon, { tintColor: tintColor }]}
      />
    ),
  };
  render()
  {
    return(
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Header
          leftComponent={<Icon name="menu" onPress={() => this.props.navigation.openDrawer()} />}
        />
        <View style={styles.text}>
        <Text>Welcome to Settings Screen</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const myStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  SplashScreen:{
    screen:SplashScreen
  },
  Login:{
    screen:Login
  },
});

const MyDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  Home:{
    screen:Home
  },
  Settings:{
    screen:Settings
  },
  Profile:{
    screen:Profile
  },
});

const MyApp = createAppContainer(MyDrawerNavigator);
const MyPrologue = createAppContainer(myStackNavigator);

export default class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
        <MyPrologue/>  
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  icon: {
    width: 24,
    height: 24,
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1
},
text:{
  flex: 1, 
  alignItems: 'center', 
  justifyContent: 'center'
},
Logocontainer:{
  flex: 1,
  justifyContent :"center",
  alignItems:"center"
},
logo:{
  width:150,
  height:150
},
button:{
  width:300,
  padding:10,
  backgroundColor:'#009999',
  alignItems: 'center'
},

input: {
  width: 300,
  height: 44,
  padding: 10,
  borderWidth: 1,
  borderColor: '#009999',
  marginBottom: 10,
},

loginbtn:{
  color:'#ffff'
},
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this cases i would suggest to use a `SwitchNavigator`, that renders pretty much like a web application. When you are passing from one screen the previous screen gets unmounted. Only the focused screen will be mounted.

I'll keep your current `StackNavigator` if you wanted to use it for the header:

First of all you need to import the `SwitchNavigator`:

```
import { createSwitchNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
```

Remove `const MyApp = createAppContainer(MyDrawerNavigator);` and change

```
const MyPrologue = createAppContainer(myStackNavigator);
```

to

```
const MyPrologue = createAppContainer(switchNavigator );
```

where `switchNavigator` is :

```
const switchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
    Authentication: {
       screen:myStackNavigator
    },
    DrawerNavigator: {
       screen: MyDrawerNavigator 
    },
 },
 {
    initialRouteName: "Authentication"
 })
```

Then your `login` function can navigate doing :

```
this.props.navigation.navigate("DrawerNavigator")
```

You can read about `SwitchNavigator` at : https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/switch-navigator.html#docsNav

Comment: Thank you sir. Works 100% createSwitchNavigation is way to go!